# Why isn't my 3 finger swipe left/right working after Sierra update?

Tags: trackpad, macos

Ever since I updated to Sierra a couple days ago, my 3 finger swipe, which gets me to my screen with the widgets like weather, clock, calendar, calculator, sticky notes, etc....is not working....at all. It seems my other gestures are working fine...but not my 3 finger to the left and back to the right. I have tried rebooting, all my boxes for gestures are checked...tried unchecking and rechecking. I am at a loss...and googling I couldn't find anything. Thank you!